# Keyboards event on coco2d (python) and pyglet

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

second question here, my first one was answer and really helped, so I'll try again.

Here is the code and the explanation:

```
import cocos
from cocos.actions import *
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet.window.key import KeyStateHandler
from cocos.director import director


keys = KeyStateHandler()

class ScaleTestLayer(cocos.layer.Layer):
    is_event_handler = True 
    def __init__(self):
        super( ScaleTestLayer, self ).__init__()
        self.sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite('grossini.png')
        self.sprite.position = 320,240
        self.drag = False
        self.add(self.sprite)
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.rect.contains(x, y) == True:
            if self.drag == False:
                scale = ScaleBy(5, duration=1)
                if buttons == pyglet.window.mouse.LEFT:
                    self.sprite.do(scale)
                if buttons == pyglet.window.mouse.MIDDLE:
                    rotate = RotateBy(180, 1)
                    self.sprite.do(rotate)
                if buttons == pyglet.window.mouse.RIGHT:
                    scale = (Reverse(scale))
                    self.sprite.do(scale)  
            else:
                self.drag = False    

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.rect.contains(x, y):
            self.drag = True
            self.sprite.position = director.get_virtual_coordinates (x, y)
        self.rect.center = self.sprite.position

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if keys[key.SPACE]:
            jump = JumpBy((5,0), duration=0.5)
            self.sprite.do(jump)
        if keys[key.RIGHT]:
            move = MoveBy((10,0), 0.5)
            self.sprite.do(move)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    cocos.director.director.init()
    test_layer = ScaleTestLayer ()
    main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene (test_layer)
    cocos.director.director.run (main_scene)
```

So here's my problem. When I press SPACE or RIGHT it does not execute the action. I printed the value and keys[key.SPACE] is return False, even though I do press those buttons. What am I missing? maybe some push_handlers? I don't know how to use it.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use push_handlers on the `KeyStateHandler` so that it is updated.  I have not used cocos2d myself, only pyglet, so this may not be the best or proper way to do it, but it should get you going.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cocos.director.director.init()
    cocos.director.director.window.push_handlers(keys)
    # Create layer, run, etc.
```

[Here is the page](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler-class.html) on using a `KeyStateHandler` in the pyglet documentation.  In pyglet you create the window yourself and attach it there, but in cocos2d the window is handled by the director.

I also found [this page](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/handling_events.html) in the cocos2d documentation, which may, or may not be, the proper way of handling key presses with cocos2d.